# How to create Topographic 3d graphs in r?

Tags: r, maps, topography

I have come across some cool `topographic maps` on **reddit** and wonder how they can be made in `r` ?

from: [reddit image post link](https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/k38e3r/topographic_3d_rendered_map_of_tamil_nadu_india/)

[image]

Is it even possible to create such maps in `r` and what kind of `data files` does it need to create them ?

Comment: look up the rayshader package: https://www.rayshader.com/   I suspect your example could have been made in blender.

Comment: Here's an older post that might help also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224035/how-to-create-a-crisp-topographical-terrain-map-with-ggplot2

Comment: thanks @Jon Spring